# Is it possible to use a DB2 variable without specifying its schema?

Tags: sql, db2

Using my JDBC connection to DB2 I specified the default schema using the URL `jdbc:db2://192.168.56.208:50000/db001:currentSchema=TZTC;`. Then, I created a DB2 variable in the default schema as:

```
create variable my_var1 smallint default 1;
```

However, when I try to set it or to display it I'm forced to specify its schema name. It fails when I try:

```
set my_var1 = 123;
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=MY_VAR1, DRIVER=3.53.95

select my_var1 from sysibm.sysdummy1;
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=MY_VAR1, DRIVER=3.53.95
```

But then, if I specify the schema name, it all works fine:

```
set tztc.my_var1 = 123; -- works
select tztc.my_var1 from sysibm.sysdummy1; -- returns 123
```

Is it possible to use a DB2 variable without specifying its schema? I would prefer to keep it schema-less as all the rest of the SQL code in the project.

Answer (score 1):

[Variables always are created in a schema](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050499.html), either [explicitly or implicitly](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050503.html). You should be able to refer to the variable without a schema name IF you are in the same schema. Thus, it should be possible to implement it in a schema-less fashion as you asked for.

The [docs have the rules](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/c0060114.html) on how the variable name is resolved.

Note that there differences between variables defined in a module and in a regular SQL (statement) context.

Comment: After reading the rules you mention, I think there may be a bug in the JDBC driver. The URL includes `:currentSchema=TZTC;` and that works for tables and views, but it seems when querying variables it defaults to another schema: `USER1` (this is the first schema I created).

Comment: According to the link provided above, schema name of an unqualified global variable searched in an sql path, and current schema is not used for such a resolution. Your schema name must be listed in the ‘currentFunctionPath’ property.

Answer (score -1):

Qualifying variable works on the iseries db2.

```
create variable mylib.my_var1 smallint default 1;
set mylib.my_var1 = 12;
```

this also works on the iseries db2.

```
create variable danny117 smallint default 1;
set danny117 = 12;
drop variable danny117;
```

Comment: After trying several options, it seems the issue is when you create/use an unqualified variable (your second case), in a schema that is not the default one, when this schema is specified with "SET CURRENT SCHEMA = SCHEMA2".

Comment: Yep that could happen.